# Swift layoutIfNeeded() not called on iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Trying to set `layoutIfNeeded()` on a `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` within a `UIScrollView` to redraw the views. Currently working on iOS 10 but it's not called on iOS 9.

```
collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I've also tried adding the code above into layout subviews but that doesn't work.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Not sure the meaning of "redraw the views". Instead of calling layoutIfNeeded in viewWillLayoutSubviews, set subviews frames. If you want the contents to be refresh call reloadData.

Comment: On iOS 9 via 4" screen sizes both CV and TB layoutIfNeeded() don't get called when I calculate the scroll view height based on CV & TV content size.